# Double Quotienting of a Ring is Isomorphic to Ring Quotient by Sum of Ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

First let me say, please edit my title if their is a more appropriate one and if this is a duplicate please direct me and close the question. I tried searching for my question, but I don't know if the theorem I am trying to prove has a name - so it was difficult to know what to search.

Also let me say that I have already tried to squeeze this theorem out of one of the isomorphism theorems, but I cant quite see how to get it, so if your hint or answer is `check the isomorphism theorems for rings' I might need more then that. I would like to understand this for personal benefit, but I am kind of limited on time.

I am specifically working with $A$ as a commutative ring with unity, $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal of $A$, and I believe $\mathfrak{b}$ is to be taken as an ideal in $A/\mathfrak{a}$, and $\mathfrak{b}'$ is the ideal in $A$ that corresponds to $\mathfrak{b}$. Then I would like to show that

$$A/\mathfrak{a}/\mathfrak{b} \approx A/(\mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{b}').$$

I tried work through the mechanics of a specific example in full formality for insight, specifically I investigated $$\mathbb{Z}/<12>/<3+<12>>$$ where <12> is my ideal generated by 12 in $\mathbb{Z}$, and <3+ <12>> is my ideal generated by the coset with representative 3 in $\mathbb{Z}/<12>$. Sorry for the horrible notation here. I am aware this is probably unusually formal approach to the "coset" approach to quotienting, But I want to make sure I understand the nuts and bolts before passing off to theorems and the more "homomorphic image" approach to quotienting. Anyways

In this example we get $\mathbb{Z}/<12>/<3+<12>>$ = $$\{ <0+<12>>, <1 + <12>>, <3+<12>> \}$$

Which should be easily isomorphically mapped to $\mathbb{Z}/<12>+<3>$ since that sum of ideals is just <12>+<3> = <3>.

If you have any advice or direction please let me know.

Comment: Note that if you have generators $\bar b_i$ for $\mathfrak b$ and you want $\mathfrak b'$ to be the corresponding ideal in the sense that it is generated by $b_i$, then $\mathfrak b'$ is not well-defined (because it is dependent on the particular representatives $b_i$), but $\mathfrak a + \mathfrak b'$ is well-defined. For example, replace $12$ by $8$ in your example, then $3$ gives the same class as $11$ modulo $8$, but for $\mathfrak b'$ we have $3\mathbb Z$ or $11 \mathbb Z$ and thus nothing definite, but we have $3 \mathbb Z + 8 \mathbb Z = 11 \mathbb Z + 8 \mathbb Z = \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the map 
$$ \phi\colon R/\def\a{\mathfrak a}\a \to R/(\a + \def\b{\mathfrak b}\b'),\quad r + \a \mapsto r + (\a+\b')  $$
which is a ring homomorphism. Note that 
$$ \phi(r+\a) = 0 \iff r \in \a + \b' \iff r + \a \in \b $$
Hence, $\ker \phi = \b$. As $\phi$ is onto, 
$$ (R/\a)/\b \cong R/(\a + \b')$$
by the homomorphism theorem for rings.

---

Addendum, regarding the comment: Suppose $r \in \a + \b'$, that is, there are $a \in \a$, $b \in \b'$ with $r = a + b$, then 
$$ r + \a = a+b+\a = b + \a \in \b $$
On the other hand, suppose $r + \a \in \b$, that is $r + \a = b + \a$ for some $b\in \b'$, or $r - b \in \a$, that is $r \in \a + \b'$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only part that I am not fully grasping is equivalence of $r \in \mathfrak{a} + \mathfrak{b}' \iff r + \mathfrak{a} \in \mathfrak{b}$. Could you please elaborate on this step?

Comment: Added something.

Comment: Thank you for breaking things down for me, much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm... none of these backflips with $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b'$ are really necessary, since $\mathfrak b'$ necessarily contains $\mathfrak a$.

Answer (score 4):

> I have already tried to squeeze this theorem out of one of the isomorphism theorems, but I cant quite see how to get it...

Well, it's almost exactly the third isomorphism theorem, so it's a little strange you didn't succeed!

Perhaps the difficulty lay in understanding the relationship of $\mathfrak b$ to $\mathfrak b'$. The corresponding ideal is just an ideal $\mathfrak b'$ of $A$ **which contains** $\mathfrak a$, such that $\mathfrak b=\frac{\mathfrak b'}{\mathfrak a}$. With that said... is there any reason to write $\mathfrak b$ anymore? Perhaps not.

The third isomorphism theorem says that $\frac{A}{\mathfrak a}/\frac{\mathfrak b'}{\mathfrak a}\cong\frac{A}{\mathfrak b'}$. You shouldn't have to write $\mathfrak a +\mathfrak b'$ because $\mathfrak a+\mathfrak b'=\mathfrak b'$.

Comment: "A little strange you didn't succeed" - if you knew how often I didn't succeed, you would not find it strange at all! Thanks for you solution though :)

Comment: @PrinceM I have had the same experience!

Comment: It really matters which kind of correspondence one wants to consider. If it's the ideal-to-ideal correspondence, then $\mathfrak b'$ is just the pre-image of $\mathfrak b$ under the canonical surjection $A \to A/\mathfrak a$ as you explained. But if it's the generator-to-generator correspondence in the sense that if $\mathfrak b$ is generated by $\bar b_i$ and one wants $\mathfrak b'$ to be the ideal generated by $b_i$, see my comment above.